# Hillshade Elevation relativity (Keeping elevations relative across various rasters)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hillshade

I have a number of various Lidar projects that I created DEM's with. I want to keep them separate (no mosaic), but need to create a hillshade from each DEM. My issue is if the max Z value in DEM#1 is 100m and the max Z value in DEM#2 is 200m, when I create their respective hillshades the max Z value is used to calculate the shade on the colour ramp.

For example, the highest elevation in DEM#1 (100m) will be white, and the highest elevation in DEM#2 (200m) will be white as well. When I want to display the hillshades side by side you wouldn't see any difference in elevation, eventhough there is a 100m difference. Has anyone come across this issue before, and if so is there a remedy?

Comment: Are you really talking about hillshade or simply elevation in grey? Same elevation in the same raster looks different on hillshade